# JavaScript search by object attribute

Tags: javascript

I have the following method used to search from a list of users by the username attribute. My confusion is that line 6 `console.log("Users filtered " + JSON.stringify(user));` displays to console the object that matches the username that I am typing in search bar. It kind of works but only for first element. For example, I have two users `vicky, valentine` and when I search by `v` I get only:

```
Users filtered {"age":"21","username":"vicky","lastUpdated":{"seconds":1601845200,"nanoseconds":0}}
```

And I get the error which points to line:
`return userObject.username.toLowerCase().includes(searchString);`:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined
    at users.js:46
    at Array.filter (<anonymous>)
    at
```

which makes me think that there must be something wrong with `userObject.username` attribute but I do not get why since it is a simple JSON object and I just want to get the `username` value. What am I doing wrong?

```
searchBar.addEventListener("keyup", (e) => {
  let searchString = e.target.value.toLowerCase();
  let filteredUsers = usersArray.filter(user => {
    let userObject = {};
    userObject = JSON.stringify(user);
    console.log("Users filtered " + JSON.stringify(user));
    return userObject.username.toLowerCase().includes(searchString);
  });
  console.log("Users filtered " + filteredUsers);
  removeUsers();
  filteredUsers.forEach((user) => {
    createUser(user);
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is with this:

```
userObject = JSON.stringify(user);
```

`JSON.stringify()` as the name implies, returns a string which wouldn't have a `username` property.

Try simplifying your filter to this:

```
let filteredUsers = usersArray.filter(user => {
    return user.username.toLowerCase().includes(searchString);
});
```